# getResources() stops working when moved into package

Tags: java, file-io, getresource

The test method below passes when my test class is in the default package and fails when I move it into a package.

The directory structure is the following:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      some.package/
    resources/
  test/
    FooTest.java // works here
    some.package/
        FooTest.java // does not work here
```

---

```
public class FooTest {

@Test
public void TestLoadImageFromFile() {
    BufferedImage loadedImage = null;
    try {
        loadedImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("someImage.png"));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertNotNull(loadedImage);
}
...
```

Comment: getClass().getResource() uses the class loader to load the resource. This means that the resource must be in the classpath to be loaded.

Comment: Why would it work in one location but not the other if it is missing from the classpath? Shouldn't it not work at all?

Comment: The linked question is COMPLETELY irrelevant. It uses ClassLoader#getResource and addresses a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, your path is relative to the calling class. Use `/someImage.png` instead.

Comment: Bingo! I tried filling in 'src/.../someImage.png' but didn't try using only the '/'